# Checking whether an integer is the product of its prime factors

Tags: java

I wrote a program that takes a positive integer, and prints “Product of my divisors” if the product of all its prime factors (excluding 1 and the number itself) is equal to its value otherwise print “Not the product of my divisors”.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int product = 1;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < x; i++)
    {
        if(x % i == 0)
        {   for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                if(i%j == 0)
                    count++;
            if(count == 2)
                product *= i;
        }
    }

    if(product == x)
        System.out.println("Product of my divisors");
    else
        System.out.println("Not the product of my divisors");       
}
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong with this code! Integer 10 is supposed to work yet it keeps giving me "Not the product of my divisors".

Comment: Because your code will run 7 times, since you have a nested for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you never reset `count`. `count` should really be declared inside the `if` block. The correct version is

```
for(int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
    if(x % i == 0) {   
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            if(i%j == 0)
                count++;
        if(count == 2)
            product *= i;
    }
}
```